# How much should I rely on Visual Studio's Auto Generated Code?

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, source-code, login

I'm reading about ASP.NET (VB.NET) and I want to built my professionally website. I'm wondering though; I'm still using the basics so I'm really just a novice, but how much should I rely on Visual Studio to create my elements?

Should I make my own text boxes and have my own login routine, or should I just use ASP.NET's login features?

I know eventually you have to use your own classes and such which is where the real coding comes in, but I'm not sure how relaible, flexible and secure the pre-wrote elements are?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are just starting out, yet you already have doubts about how reliable, flexible and secure the auto-generated code of an extremely mature IDE is? ;) Concentrate on learning, and stop worrying about stuff like that, even if the auto-generated code is somehow problematic, you'll need to familiarize yourself with the language for at least a few months before you fully understand why it's problematic and more importantly what you can do about it.

Answer (score 5):

**Short Answer:** Start with analyzing generated HTML and solid fundamentals of HTML knowledge.

It is always a BIG back draw to rely on generated code without analyzing and understanding from where **this magic comes from**. You may end-up with hours of maintainability issues if you push such code to the production.

In another words, know your code and its behavior before relying on it, otherwise you will have a lot of gotcha!

Comment: While I agree that not analyzing and understanding how the code is generated can be a problem.  One needs to first actually understand the code that is generated so they can then start to question the code that is generated.  This only comes through experience and in most cases the code generated is at the same level even the best programmer can write on their own.  It might have maintainability issues but it will function the same.

Comment: @Ramhound, yes as i have also mentioned "know your code and its behavior before relying on it"

Answer (score 2):

The "real coding" comes in where you're adding unique value to whatever it is you're developing.

If you're spending time re-inventing the wheel and choosing to write what will - almost inevitably - be less comprehensive implementations to solve common problems then you're not really adding value.

Fundamentally therefore you trust the generated code (or packaged/library code) until you have good reason not to.

However, I suspect you don't mean "code" you actually mean "markup" (i.e. HTML and, by extension, CSS - and javascript, though that's code again!) and that's a somewhat different question - and a somewhat broader one since there are a number of possibilites in terms of how that markup is specified and generated. Old web forms code does things that are "not nice" although, as it turns out, are more than adequate to a lot of purposes whereas with MVC you have very fine grained control of what appears in the client browser. (And with the latest version of web forms MS has attempted to ensure that their markup is a lot cleaner.)

Ultimately if you're putting up a "public" facing website (which is the implication) you want to have a high level of control over the markup. There are any number of ways you can do this with the MS stack - ASP.NET MVC is the "in house" tool - there are others.

Answer (score 1):

Im not going to pretend that I am an amazing .net developer, but I do ok. And I am always getting better. And although I agree that totally relying on visual studio auto generated code isn't the best idea, I do think it serves its purpose for learning.

It was through auto generated CRUDs in MVC that I first understood how to make them from scratch, by reading and understanding. How to edit that code and how to properly manage, edit and build upon it, I learnt how to utilise partial classes better and it often pointed me in the direction of things to research and new elements I should learn about.

Its a useful tool, and its normally fairly reliable. In my honest opinion whilst your learning use it, just make sure you learn something from it as well.